# android-support-v7-appcompat support library not woking with android 2.2

Tags: android

When I have import android-support-v7-appcompat support library in my workspace and add to my project with android 4.4 then its working fine but less than api level 11 its's not working.
I used it for action bar in my project.
When i am working with android 2.2 then it gives error in my console. Thanks

```
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:122: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:125: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:133: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:137: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:141: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:44: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:64: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:68: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:72: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:76: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:80: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode.Inverse'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:104: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:108: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:112: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title.Inverse'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:116: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:84: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:88: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:92: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:96: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:100: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\styles_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\styles_base.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:159: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Spinner'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:161: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:153: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:156: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:147: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:150: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:167: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:171: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:175: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupMenu'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:178: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:182: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:186: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:190: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:194: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:200: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Holo.SearchResult.Title'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:204: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Holo.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:212: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Holo.SearchResult.Title'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:216: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Holo.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\styles_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\styles_base.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:225: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:dividerPadding'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:224: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:showDividers'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:33: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:44: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:41: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:67: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2014-01-27 17:01:03 - MainActivity] F:\xevoke_workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:94: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.
```

my property file

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.

    target=android-8
    android.library.reference.1=../android-support-v7-appcompat
```

Comment: Just an idea, so far: did you add the android-support-v4 compatibility library, as well?

Comment: Are you using AppCompact theme as well?

Comment: post project.properties file

Comment: Sharj@ yes i have added android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" theme in my menifest file

Comment: pskink@ i have posted my property file.

Comment: Use the library v4 maybe ^^

Comment: Yume117@ i have already using v4 library so it'd working on android 4.4

Comment: your project build target (target=android-8) is wrong, change it via project-propertiies > android

Comment: pskink@ you mean like that project-propertiies > android-8

Comment: no: right click on project then click properties then android

Comment: pskink@ I have to run this project over android 2.2 and all higher version so i set it to android 2.2 in my project-propertiies > android

Comment: see this http://samliu2.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-project-build-target-vs.html?m=1

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit old, but I had the same problem (and a Git branch working, while another branch not working), and it turned out that it was related to the project's ***target*** Android API. My project's target API was too low (8) (right click on your project > properties > Android > select your desired target). I think the support library (AppCompat) requires you to set your target API to **at least API level 14 (Android 4.0)**. Please note that target API is different from the min API. It's indeed the MAX, the highest API that you think your app will support, or the highest API you have tested your app against.

Comment: very good i never understand that prob but now i have come to configure it out